# Make a class that holds a different number of settings per property generic?

Tags: c#, oop

I have to set some properties at run time, but the issue I run into is that some properties have 5 settings while another may have 3 or 4.  Is there a way I can create a generic class that could hold any number of settings for a property without having to write multiple classes?

One example is that I have a property called `Color` which the only setting is the `Color`, but in another scenario, I have a property called `Mask` which has a setting for `MaskType` and the `Mask`

Comment: sounds like a dictionary

Comment: I somehow feel I'm not understanding your definition of property, settings and so on. Mind explaining?

Comment: Examples would help us understand exactly what you mean. Are the properties of the same type? Are they different types? Can you use `dynamic`?

Comment: @Alex, but a Dictionary holds a key and value, I have a key, but I have more than 1 value in some cases.

Comment: @Oded - I put a couple examples.

Comment: @Xaisoft: To me, Mask and Color sounds like a struct, which both are a field in a class?

Comment: @Marc-AndréJutras - What they are doesn't really matter to me and those are just 2 examples?  I am looking for a way to represent a property no matter how many settings make it up.  I don't want to have to create 10 different classes for each property if they had a different amount of settings.

Comment: @Xaisoft: So... You have a class that have a unknown number of field? Or a class with an unknown field? Are you asking about a Generic class?

Comment: @Xaisoft, use a dictionary that holds String -> Object, or String -> List<Something>

Comment: If you're objects are really that complex and involved then it's all the more reason to make actual defined classes for them all.  If you try to use a Dictionary or ExpandoObject for something that complex it will become unmanageable very quickly.

Answer (score 2):

You might like to have a look around the [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx). It allows you to add properties and their values dynamically, though it does require .NET 4 or upwards.

Comment: i personally don't like Expando objects, or dynamic objects at all for that matter, but it's a creative idea nevertheless

Comment: @Alex To be honest, I've never used it myself - I just remember reading about it and it seemed like it fit what the OP asked. (Moreso prior to the examples being added, I must admit)

Answer (score 2):

It's a classic, and the solution really depends on how you wish to access your properties.
In ASP.NET the cache uses something like:

```
public class Cache
{
   private Dictionary<string, object> CachedValues;

   public object this [string arg]
   {
       get
       {
           return CachedValues[arg];
       }
   }
}
```

Or you can use `Tuple<T1, T2, T3...>`

Or you can use `dynamic` and anonymous types

Answer (score 1):

I think it is always better to write individual classes that will represent your individual objects. In my opinion you will only create more problems trying to write a generic class. Perhaps have a look at the Factory or Adapter patterns to decide on which of the classes to use in different scenarios.

Comment: Color and Mask are two different objects and should be handled that way